# can't locate db4o database file

Tags: database, file, db4o

Hello I'm coding a simple CRUDE application that runs perfectly using JSF and DB4O.
I can add and list all the entities normally without errors.
I've used this code to persist the entities

```
bd = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(configuration, "db.data");
        bd.store(client);
        bd.commit();
```

the problem is that I cant locate the db.data file. I,ve done a search in the whole PC and still cant find it.
soo where DB4O store those entities, how is it possible??
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It must be in your project execution path. Usually db4o file name is called with extension `yap`. Better you can use relative path to the database file like

```
String dbPath = "c:/db/project.yap"; // better read from project resource
EmbeddedObjectContainer openFile = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(dbPath);
```